# kubernetes jee: Map resources property file

Tags: jakarta-ee, kubernetes, quartz-scheduler

I've this `quartz.properties` file into `src/main/resources` folder project:

```
org.quartz.jobStore.class = net.joelinn.quartz.jobstore.RedisJobStore
org.quartz.jobStore.host = redisbo
```

As you can see, I need to change `org.quartz.jobStore.host` according to current environment.

I mean, according to the environment my project has to be deployed, this value has to change as well.

All my environment are on kubernetes/openshift.

I don't quite figure out how to create a configmap in order to map this property of my `src/main/resources/quartz.properties`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can configure as following steps.

- Create `configmap` using `quartz.properties` file as follows.

  ```
      # kubectl create configmap quartz-config --from-file=quartz.properties
  ```
- set the volume as `configmap` created as follows.

  ```
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Pod
  metadata:
    name: test
  spec:
    containers:
      - name: test-container
        image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
        command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "ls /src/main/resources" ]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config-volume
          mountPath: /src/main/resources
    volumes:
      - name: config-volume
        configMap:
          name: quartz-config
    restartPolicy: Never
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider creating an External Service, so you keep your redisbo as it is in your code and use kubernetes to map to external dns.  We use this technique a lot.

This guide is super helpful

https://akomljen.com/kubernetes-tips-part-1/